# Facebook Integration in iphone?

Tags: iphone

I am using the Facebook iOS Sdk for iPhone. I initialize the Facebook instance

facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:kAppId];

I use the facebook sdk and get login user information also it's work in simulator show pop view for login page at the same time when i run in device it directly connect to the device facebook but i don't need to connect to device facebook just i need show pop view for login

please guide me.

thanks for advance

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the FBLoginDialog class available in the SDK, in the authorize method of Facebook.m you should find how they do it for non multitasking devices...